# Figure out attendance needed for remaining days to reach attendance goal

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Trying to come up with attendance percentage needed to reach a goal.

To simplify a student to date has gone to school 140 of the 150 days and therefore their current attendance is .93

There are 70 days remaining and the annual goal is .95

What would the formula be to figure out what the remaining attendance percent needed to be to reach .95? Thinking they must be weighted to be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

The annual goal is .95 of 150+70=220 days, therefore the student can miss 0.05*220=11 days. He has already missed 10, so he must show up 69 of the 70 remaining days.

---

In general:

- Compute the number of days the student can miss using:
  $$\text{Days that can be missed} = (1-\text{attendance goal})\cdot\text{number of days per year}$$
- Calculate the number of days the student has missed.
- Substract to find the number of days the student can still miss.
- Read the question again to make sure you actually answer the question if you have a test.

Comment: Looking more for one formula.  This would apply to entire school and tried to simplify it down to a student for the example so I can create a calculated field.  This is so simple I am guessing it is just monday and my brain is still on the weekend.

Comment: This approach can be used for any student as well.

Comment: Yes finally I am getting it. Thanks for your help.